# Is this a complementizer what?

Tags: complements

> He bought Harry a hamburger and they sat down on plastic seats to eat them. Harry kept looking around. Everything looked so strange, somehow.
>
> "You all right, Harry? Yer very quiet," said Hagrid.
>     Harry wasn't sure he could explain. He'd just had the best birthday of his life –– and yet –– he chewed his hamburger, trying to find the words.
>
> "Everyone thinks I'm special," he said at last. "All those people in the Leaky Cauldron, Profes-sor Quirrell, Mr. Ollivander... but I don't know anything about magic at all. How can they expect great things? I'm famous and I can't even remember ***what (1)*** I'm famous for. I don't know ***what happened*** when Vol-, sorry –– I mean, ***the night my parents died (2)***." 
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

I guess *what (1)* is a complementizer that moved forth from *for*'s complement. And it’s the pronoun referring to *what happened the night my parents died (2)*, or short form of this. Is this a proper parsing?

Comment: The two free relative clauses are not related, grammatically or syntactically -- only rhetorically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I can't even remember what I'm famous for" contains two clauses.

"What I'm famous for" is a "wh- clause". It can be considered to be the result transformation of the sentence "I'm famous for what" by a process called [wh- movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wh-movement) where by "what" moves to the front.

The entire clause is [nominalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalization). That is to say, "what I'm famous for" serves as a big noun.

The pattern "I cannot remember [  ]" requires a noun phrase, or a nominalized clause to fill in the blank.

I do not believe that "what" serves as a complementizer: not in your sentence, or anywhere else.

There is also no evidence of any invisible complementizer in the sentence.

Nominalized clauses can be joined without a complementizer, because they denote something (similarly to a noun) whereas complementized clauses represent themselves as clauses, more or less.

There are wh- words that are complementizers, such: whom, which, whether.

For instance, consider:

> The song *which* you like is playing on the radio.

There is no grammatical way to use "what" in a similar way as a complementizer. "The song what you like" is not grammatical.

And, conversely, "which you like" does not nominalize: "This is which I like" is not grammatical.